RTL text makes the Staging Ground's "last action" timestamp render incorrectly
When a user with RTL text in their username (in this case, Arabic) performs an action in the Staging Ground, the "last action" timestamp's rendering breaks, splitting the number and the "seconds/mins/hours ago" text:

This isn't the case for LTR text:


Yikes. This might be the worst unicode-esque problem I've seen yet. I hope I never have to deal with it.
